# best way to store a variable available to every session in php

Tags: php

I wanted to know what would be a good way for storing the information required by a something like a hit counter. I was wondering if this was possible using some session-like technique, but available to everyone. I am concerned about speed/performance, and not memory usage since the data to be store is minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of thing people use [APC](http://php.net/apc_add) and/or memcached for.

Comment: +1.  You can optionally persist the counter to disk/DB every N-minutes via cron, if you need to.  Redis may also be worth a look in that case, as it has persistence built in.

Answer (score 1):

Store it in a database!

If you app doesnt already use a DB you almost certainly have sqlite installed as part of your php installtion.
Its about 10 lines of code to connect and read the value.

If you app already uses a db its one extra table with one extra column.

Comment: +1.  A db is definitely an adequate solution for small-scale applications, and it handles concurrency, unlike a simple file-based solution.  It may not perform quite as well as memcached etc., but it might be worth keeping things simple and sticking with your existing datastore (rather than adding a second) in some contexts.

Comment: Porbably scales better than memcachehd once you have more than one server running!